# Nested IFs vs logical opearators in PHP. Which is a good practice?

Tags: php, syntax

I have inherited some project and I'm trying to add some functionalities, but I have hard time reading it. One of the most annoying things are really deeply nested loops/conditions. I've got something like that:

```
if (con1){
    if(con2){
        if(con3){
            do_something;
        }
    }
}
```

and I changed it to

```
if(con1&&con2&&con3){
    do_something;
}
```

am I being dumb for not seeing some obvious advantage of this way, or am I working on dumb code?

@edit:
I know that if I wanted code like

```
if (con1){
    if(con2){
            do_something;

    }
    do_something_else;
}
```

the second way wouldn't work, but I'm asking only for those narrow situation where I need all conditions true.

Comment: There is no "better". They are different, particularly when used in any meaningful fashion with `else if/else` statements and changing one form to another *cannot* be blindly done. In the case where they are semantically equivalent then - use whichever you prefer (I find it changes based upon *intent* and expectations of *future* code), but save "refactoring" for things that really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using deeply nested if-else statements since they are harder to read and error-prone to maintain. If all you want to do is check if all those conditions are true, then simply go with the second version. It is *much* more readable and clearly conveys the message.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't say either way is "better" than the other, but they each have their advantages. To me it really just depends on how much other code is involved in those if statements. If there are actually eight different states that all require different code, depending on the values of `con1` `con2` and `con3`, then having nested ifs makes it easier to group similar code together. But on the other hand, if you only care about the single case when `con1 && con2 && con3`, then your latter example is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that shortest is best. So if you only need all of them to be true, go for if(con1 && con2 && con3).